# Counting values from a child level category in a tree, and applying to all parents in PHP or MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a maximum 5 level tree of categories for eCommerce site in mysql, tree is generated based on parent_id approach, I also have a column in table **total** to show how many products in each category.

I was asked a week back to implement a new functionality, to show how many products in each parent_id of categories, as showing below the example of database table values in a PHP array.

[image: preview of desired results]

The original array is as following:

```
$array = [
'101' => [
    'total' => null,
    'array' => [
        '102' => 4,
        '103' => 24,
        '104' => [
            'total' => null,
            'array' => [
                '105' => 9,
                '106' => [
                    'total' => null,
                    'array' => [
                        '107' => 2,
                        '108' => 3
                    ]
                ],
                '109' => [
                    'total' => null,
                    'array' => [
                        '110' => 2,
                        '111' => 3
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ],
        '112' => [
            'total' => null,
            'array' => [
                '113' => 2,
                '114' => 3
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
'115' => [
    'total' => null,
    'array' => [
        '116' => 2,
        '117' => 3
    ]
]];
```

I have tried many approaches during this week, and nothing worked out for me, with travelling recursive, but it does not help either, I am still unsure how to travel recursive backward from each highest tree level.

What would be your approach to calculate and update these values on the database?

following is mysql table structure and dummy data:

> INSERT INTO dummy_categories (id,parent_id,total) VALUES
>       (101,0,NULL),(102,101,4),(103,101,24),(104,101,NULL),
>       (105,104,9),(106,104,NULL),(107,106,2),(108,106,3),
>       (109,104,NULL),(110,109,2),(111,109,3),(112,101,NULL),
>       (113,112,2),(114,112,3),(115,0,NULL),(116,115,2),(117,115,3);

Comment: How big is your array? Why not re-calculate all totals from the bottom up? You may find this will only take a split second for the whole thing, and there is no point trying to update just part of the tree.

Comment: I hate nested navigation in PHP arrays - you always want to work backwards; e.g. the URL would give you category id `108` and you need to then figure out which branches are active *above* it - this can lead to horrible recursive functions or loops. I found the best way to deal with this is to create an XML (DOMDocument) object out of it and use your database IDs in your DOM IDs. You can then `getElementById` to traverse the node tree **up** ... in this case you could probably also calculate your totals after the fact by counting the node children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I performed summing up child totals to all parents:

```
class CountChildValuesToParents {
    private $_nodes;
    private $_node;
    private $_parentId;
    private $_data;

    public function updateData($data) {
        $this->_data = [];
        $this->_node = 0;
        $this->_nodes = [];
        $data = $this->buildTree($data);
        $this->update($data, $data[0]);
        $this->emptyNodes();
        foreach ($this->_data as $id => $total) {
            UPDATE dummy_categories SET total=$total WHERE id=$id
        }

    }
    private function buildTree($data) {
        $cats = [];
        foreach ($data as $v) {
            $cats[$v['parent_id']][$v['id']] = $v;
        }
        return $cats;
    }
    private function update(&$p, $childs) {
        foreach ($childs as $id => $v) {
            if (isset($p[$id])) {
                if (!$v['parent_id']) {
                    $this->emptyNodes();
                } elseif ($v['parent_id'] != $this->_parentId) {
                    $this->emptyNode($v['parent_id']);
                }
                $this->_parentId = $id;
                $this->_nodes = [$id => 0] + $this->_nodes;
                $this->update($p, $p[$id]);
            } elseif (isset($v['total'])) {
                $this->updateNodes((int)$v['total']);
            }
        }
    }
    private function updateNodes($value) {
        foreach ($this->_nodes as $id => $v) {
            $this->_nodes[$id] += $value;
        }
    }
    private function emptyNode($parentId) {
        if (!isset($this->_nodes[$parentId])) {
            die('ERROR: Node in _nodes not exist.');
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->_nodes); $i++) {
            $key = key($this->_nodes);
            if ($key == $parentId) {
                return;
            }

            if (isset($this->_data[$key])) {
                die('ERROR: Node in _data already exists.');
            }
            $this->_data[$key] = $this->_nodes[$key];
            unset($this->_nodes[$key]);
        }
    }
    private function emptyAllNodes() {
        foreach ($this->_nodes as $k => $v) {
            if (isset($this->_data[$k])) {
                die('ERROR: Node in _data already exists.');
            }
            $this->_data[$k] = $v;
        }
        $this->_nodes = [];
    }
}
```